# I get Error 2042 when I try to use Vlookup in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code that searches for a value in an array and return its corresponding value from another column (vlookup). When I just access the value directly, not using vlookup, it works without errors, but any variant of lookup or vlookup doesn't work. The data type in the searched range is String.

Here's the Sub Process:

```
Sub ProcessWorksheet1(EngagementKeyword)

    Dim DummyVariable As String
    Dim EngagementName1 As String
    Dim EngagementName2 As String

    DummyVariable = Sheets("PDR Data").Range("B5").Value
    EngagementName1 = [VLOOKUP("ABC", 'PDR DATA'!B5, 1, FALSE)]
    EngagementName2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("ABC", Sheets("PDR DATA").Range("B5"), 1, False)
    'EngagementName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(EngagementKeyword, Range("B4:V119"), 1, True)

    'ChargedHours = Range("A4:V4").AutoFilter (Field:=2, Criteria1:=DummyVariable)
End Sub
```

The debugging and relevant Watches:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what this `EngagementName1 = [LOOKUP("ABC", 'PDR DATA'!B5, FALSE)]` is... get rid of it for starters.

Comment: I assume that you have incorrect use of the [Lookup](https://www.automateexcel.com/functions/lookup-formula-excel/) function. According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.lookup) there should not be a boolean argument. As a result of quick research found that `Error 2042 represents a #N/A error.`

Comment: For Christ's sake, please group your `Dim` statements at the top of your procedure. Your sequence may well be easier for you to write but it certainly is more difficult for me to read. With that said, why do you ask about `VLOOKUP` while your code uses `LOOKUP`? With that question out of the way, why do you insist on VBA using an Excel function? Have you considered that VBA has its own ways? Coming to the end of this tirade, bear in mind that the data type of what you look up is critical (but not disclosed in your question). Try looking for the data type your lookup range holds.

Comment: Why is your lookup range a single cell?!

Comment: @SJR It's to illustrate that the value can be returned directly without errors.

Comment: So that tells you that B5 is not "ABC". Your question is unclear.

Comment: You need wildcards if you are looking for a string within a bigger string.

Comment: Do you intend to look for "ABC" string only in the "B5" cell of `"PDR DATA"` sheet?

Comment: @FaneDuru I am ultimately trying to look for a value containing "ABC" in the range B5:B119 of the `"PDR DATA"` sheet.

Comment: And? Are you sure that in the specific range, on column B:B (column 1) does a string "ABC" exist? If not, the error you receive is not a VBA error. It is the error returned by the function when it doesn't find anything in search range (#N/A)...

Comment: @FaneDuru What is there is a string containing "ABC", `"TY14 ABC Compliance"`.

Comment: "String variables are used to store text". Your text "ABC" is a string...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes... I don't know where you're going with this.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it correct? Microsoft says that, not me... Let me find a link. Look [here](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/variables.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206934/discussion-between-mindvoyager-and-faneduru).